# Cannot invoke substringToIndex with an arguement list type int

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get this line to work:

```
textView.text = textView.text.substringToIndex(count(textView.text.utf16) - 1)
```

error:  Cannot invoke substringToIndex with an arguement list type int

Comment: It tells you in the error.. you need to make it an Int (or NSInteger)

Comment: @ElGuapo That is incorrect. The error is saying it should NOT be an Int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`substringToIndex` takes a `String.Index` which is different from an Int. If you want to take the whole string minus the last character, you could do

```
textView.text = textView.text.substringToIndex(advance(textView.text.endIndex, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

To advance David's answer, the issue basically arose due to difference between Foundation's `NSString` class and Swift's `String` type.

The method belongs to type `String` needs `<String.Index>`, because string handling in Swift is different from `NSString`'s implementation.

To clarify, `NSString` instances do not use Unicode characters, whereas Swift needs comprehensive approach to `String`s regarding usage of Unicode characters. Hence, you should be careful when casting `String`s to `NSString`s, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension:

**Swift 2.3**

```
extension String
{   
    func substringToIndex(index: Int) -> String
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > self.characters.count)
        {
            print("index \(index) out of bounds")
            return ""
        }
        return self.substringToIndex(self.startIndex.advancedBy(index))
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
extension String
{
    func substring(to index: Int) -> String
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > self.characters.count)
        {
            print("index \(index) out of bounds")
            return ""
        }
        return self.substring(to: self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
    }
}
```

And use:

```
textView.text = textView.text.substringToIndex(textView.text.characters.count - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for SWIFT 3:-

```
if textView.text.characters.count > 100 {

            let tempStr = textView.text
            let index = tempStr?.index((tempStr?.endIndex)!, offsetBy: 100 - (tempStr?.characters.count)!)
            textView.text = tempStr?.substring(to: index!)
        }
    }
```